# Visual Studio 2012 - Design View is Wrong

Tags: css, visual-studio

Im using VS 2012, and I had some div's styled to have a 3 column layout.  When I run the project, the layout is accurate, but when I preview it in the design layout, the div's are stacking, rather than showing in a column layout.  Is there a way for me to change preferences for the layout designer?  Here's some screenshots...

**Incorrect:**

[image: Incorrect Layout]

---

**Correct (When I run my project):**

[image]

Comment: What kind of file are you working on in the designer here?

Comment: Just an ASPX page with some standard HTML.. styling the div's to be in a column format via CSS, nothing super fancy